# Raw Depth map SDK for IPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-x

I did some search and found various examples, documentation on iPhone X Face ID and how it can be used for various stuff like authentication, animated emojis.

Wanted to check if there is an API/SDK to get the raw depth map from iPhone X sensor to the app?

From my understanding the depth calculation is done based on the projected pattern. This can be used to get depth profile of any object in front of the sensor. (Might be dependent on the texture of the object.)

Answer (score 8):

You'll need at least the iOS 11.1 SDK in Xcode 9.1 (both in beta as of this writing). With that, [`builtInTrueDepthCamera`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice.devicetype/2933376-builtintruedepthcamera) becomes one of the [camera types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice.devicetype) you use to select a capture device:

```
let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInTrueDepthCamera, for: .video, position: .front)
```

Then you can go on to set up an `AVCaptureSession` with the TrueDepth camera device, and can use that capture session to capture depth information much like you can with the back dual camera on iPhone 7 Plus and 8 Plus:

- Turn on depth capture for photos with `AVCapturePhotoOutput.`[`isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput/2866565-isdepthdatadeliveryenabled), then snap a picture with `AVCapturePhotoSettings.`[`isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotosettings/2866562-isdepthdatadeliveryenabled). You can read the [`depthData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephoto/2873909-depthdata) from the [`AVCapturePhoto`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephoto) object you receive after the capture, or turn on `embedsDepthDataInPhoto` if you just want to fire and forget (and read the data from the captured image file later).
- Get a live feed of depth maps with [`AVCaptureDepthDataOutput`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedepthdataoutput). That one is like the video data output; instead of recording directly to a movie file, it gives your delegate a timed sequence of image (or in this case, depth) buffers. If you're also capturing video at the same time, [`AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedataoutputsynchronizer) might be handy for making sure you get coordinated depth maps and color frames together.

As Apple's [Device Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Cameras/Cameras.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH107-SW38) documentation notes, you need to select the [`builtInTrueDepthCamera`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice.devicetype/2933376-builtintruedepthcamera) device to get any of these depth capture options. If you select the front-facing `builtInWideAngleCamera`, it becomes like any other selfie camera, capturing only photo and video.

---

Just to emphasize: from an API point of view, capturing depth with the front-facing TrueDepth camera on iPhone X is a lot like capturing depth with the back-facing dual cameras on iPhone 7 Plus and 8 Plus. So if you want a deep dive on how all this depth capture business works in general, and what you can do with captured depth information, check out the [WWDC17 Session 507: Capturing Depth in iPhone Photography](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/507/) talk.

Comment: I've set up my AVCaptureDevice as you indicate, and when I try to enable depth data delivery on my AVCapturePhotoOutput object I get an error stating " *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCapturePhotoOutput setDepthDataDeliveryEnabled:] Depth data delivery is not supported in the current configuration'".  Do you know what may be causing this?  It's been a long time since I've developed for iOS, so it's possible/probable that I'm doing something obvious.

Comment: @rickster The depth data that is returned by the front-facing camera, is it possible to return more than 8-bit data/per pixel?