# Capture user photo from iOS Biometrics authentication

Tags: ios, face-recognition, biometrics, face-id

I want to capture the user's photo taken by Face ID Biometrics in iOS.

However, the iOS Biometrics does not return image data. It only return success or error as results.

My main idea is to take a user's photo and utilize iPhone capability to verify that the photo is for a real person not a fooled photo.

iPhone is using Camera, Infrared and Dot Projector to verify that a real person is front of the camera.

Then I want to upload this photo to our servers.

```
func authenticate(completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> ())){

    let authenticationContext = LAContext()
    var error:NSError?

    let isValidSensor : Bool = authenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error)

    if isValidSensor {
        authenticationContext.evaluatePolicy(
            .deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics,
            localizedReason: "Touch / Face ID authentication",
            reply: { (success, error) -> Void in
                if(success) {
                    completion(true)
                } else {
                    completion(false)
                }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: in here you need to use coreImage framework for identify the face detection, for ref : [Face Detection in iOS Using Core Image](https://www.appcoda.com/face-detection-core-image)

Comment: You might be able use face tracking from ARKit, but remember there are millions of iPhone devices, including the new iPhone SE that don't have faceid.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik The link is about face detection in images and thats what I want to avoid. I want to detect the face and make sure it is not an image placed in front of the camera. I want to make sure it is a real person in front of the camera.

Comment: @Paulw11 I am using the ARKit to detect faces. But it also detect faces in pictures. I want to distinguish between pictures and real faces.

Comment: I understand that, but even if you can access face depth data, what are you plans for the vast majority of devices that don't have a depth sensor?

Comment: @Paulw11 We will provide the devices for the app users "internal users".

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46413389/raw-depth-map-sdk-for-iphone-x/46455058#46455058

Comment: @Paulw11 The answer in that question is about receiving depth data. I tried it and I received depth data for both real 3D face and picture 2D face. How to distinguish between the two?

Comment: Did you perform any analysis on the depth data? I would expect a real face to show depth variation across facial features (you would expect the nose to be closer to the camera than the eyes for example) while a photo would have uniform depth since it is a flat piece of paper. There is a wwdc session from 2018 with some sample code that might help. https://developer.apple.com/wwdc18/503